# .NET .resx files: why does name attribute often start with &gt;&gt;

Tags: .net, winforms, resx

In many .resx files I come across something like this:

```xml
<data name="&gt;&gt;OurLabel.Name" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>OurLabel</value>
</data>
```

My question is: why does the attribute `name` in many cases - but not always - start with `&gt;&gt;`?

Comment: Well, of course, what this actually means is that the resource name is `<<OurLabel.Name` because `&gt;` is just the XML encoded form of `<`, but still a good question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It looks like some kind of convention, with a special meaning or reason or effect, but I can't find out what it is. And `&gt;` is `>` of course :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You found this in the .resx file for a Winforms form with its Localizable property set to True.  `&gt;` is the xml encoding for the `>` character so the property value name that is getting saved is ">>OurLabel.Name".

Other properties that you'll see treated like this are Type, Parent, ZOrder.

What is special about them is that they are *design-time* properties.  Extra ones that are added by the designer for a control.  The problem with the designer adding these properties is that they can cause *ambiguity*.  The best example I can think of is  intentionally causing such an ambiguity:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyLabel : Label {
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Drop this one on a form and now there are *two* Type properties for the control.  You'll see them back in the .resx file like this:

```
 <data name="myLabel1.Type" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Example</value>
 </data>
 <data name="&gt;&gt;myLabel1.Type" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>MyLabel, WindowsFormsApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</value>
 </data>
```

Note the difference between "myLabel1.Type" and ">>myLabel1.Type".  Problem solved.

You'll also see the "$this." prefix used.  It disambiguates between the name of a property of the form and the name of a control on the form.

Comment: Answer accepted, thanks.
Values for Type, Parent and ZOrder are indeed present as well, with the same `>>` prefix.
I tried my best finding a reference for this (MSDN or otherwise), but have not been able to find it (anyone??)

Comment: Also, only now I realize that all properties prefixed with `>>` are not subject to Localization, because they are all 'technical' / 'non-linguistic' properties. Maybe this is another SO-question :-) but I wonder what benefit there is from storing even those properties in a resx file, if Localization is not the reason?